# iPhone SDK: Welcome video

Tags: iphone, objective-c, video

Right, I have a video ready for it to be played on start up of my iphone App. How can I get this implemented into my Xcode project?

I would like it to load as soon as the app is loaded, and the after it is played, to follow onto the correct view controller where the main bulk of my programming is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not clear which part you have trouble with:

1. Playing video and getting notified when it's finished: See "[How do i initiate video playback in my code?](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/codinghowtos/AudioAndVideo/index.html#VIDEO-INITIATE_VIDEO_PLAYBACK_IN_MY_CODE)" from [Audio/Video coding howtos](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/codinghowtos/AudioAndVideo).
2. Starting it as soon the application is loaded: [applicationDidFinishLaunching](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationDidFinishLaunching:) is a good place to call.

The issue is that you'll see your window's content until the video is loaded, one possible workaround:

- add an image of the first frame to
  the window, and hide that image when
  the video finished
- you should also
  add this first frame as
  [Default.png](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/codinghowtos/Tools/#GENERAL-CREATE_THE_IMAGE_THAT_APPEARS_IN_MY_APPLICATION_S_WINDOW_ON_LAUNCH) to show it until
  your application is loaded
- you might need to hide the status bar on startup ([UIStatusBarHidden](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPRuntimeConfig/Articles/PListKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-SW15)) and  show it when the movie finished ([setStatusBarHidden](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/setStatusBarHidden:animated:)).